# Let $S=\{1\le a \le n:(a,n)=1,a^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n\}$ are there composite numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $S=\{1\le a \le n:(a,n)=1,a^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n\}$

Are there prime numbers $n$ such that $S\neq\emptyset$? are there any composite numbers $n$ such that $S=\emptyset$?
For the first one i think that there are not any prime numbers $n$ for which the $S$ is not empty from Fermat's little theorem.What about the scond one?

Comment: For the composites, check out [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: the first case its right with the fermat little theorem?

Comment: Yes, Fermat's Little Theorem is a particular case of Euler's Theorem.

Comment: So for $S\neq\emptyset$ there aren't $n$ prime numbers and there are (Carmichael numbers) $n$ composite numbers such that $S=\emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, you're right.